# Is it possible to refer to a specific instance function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Given the following type class, I would like for some instance `Foo X`, to be able to refer to `baz` directly. Since `baz` doesn't (directly) take an argument of type `a`, I don't know how to do this.

```
class Foo a where
  bar :: a -> Int
  baz :: (a -> Int, a -> Int)
  baz =  ((\x -> 1), (\x -> 2))
```

I can easily do `bar x` if `x :: X`. But if I try to do a qualified import of the module that `Foo X` is in, call it `FooX`, and do `FooX.baz` I'll get a `Not in scope: FooX.baz` message.

Comment: You can make use of the [`TypeApplications` extension](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/TypeApplication), or specify the signature of `baz` when you use it.

Comment: `baz :: (X -> Int, X -> Int)`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - great, that seems to work, if you want to propose that as an answer.